# Android studio force shutdown laptop?

Tags: android

I have windows system with 4gb ram and core i3 processor.I have configured android studio IDE.The laptop is automatically force shutdown while doing below tasks
1.while making build or import new project  android studio would start normally up to the point where background task tell its's indexing file then my laptop would stop.

How to solve this problem? Any one please give the solution for this?

Comment: android studio is very resource intensive, i'm not sure if the specs you've given match the minimum requirements to run it

Answer (score 1):

Try this: open `gradle.properties` file, find parameter `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m` and decrease amount of memory to 1000m or less, so `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1000m`
I can't test it, sorry if it not help.

Comment: Wher i need to edit this value either in  android project gradle.properties or like as C:\users\gradle.properties

Comment: Android project